# How to copy lines up to a certain character from one text file into another in C?

Tags: c, string

I have a text file, "input", in which some lines contain the character '$'. I want to copy this file into a new text file, "output", but with all the lines truncated after (and including) the '$' character (if present).

I have tried the following:

```
while (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, input) != NULL)
{
    strcpy(tmp_line, line);
    cmt_ptr = strchr(tmp_line, '$');
    if (cmt_ptr != NULL)
    {
        *cmt_ptr = '\n';
    }
    fputs(tmp_line, output);
}
```

This compiles, but all the text after '$' in each line gets copied into a new line.

I then tried this:

```
while (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, input) != NULL)
{
    strcpy(tmp_line, line);
    cmt_ptr = strchr(tmp_line, '$');
    if (cmt_ptr != NULL)
    {
        strtok(tmp_line, '$');
    }
    fputs(tmp_line, output);
}
```

but I get an error message saying "Access violation reading location".

Can someone please advise me on how to correct the code?

Comment: Why are you using `fgets`?  Read one character at a time.  If it is a `$`, change state to "don't-print".  If it is a newline, reset state to "print".  Output the character if the state is "print".

Comment: Don't forget that strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. All standard function that handles strings will look for the null-terminator character `'\0'` to know when the string end. You change the `'$'` to a newline, but you never change the terminator, it will still be somewhere after the newline.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thank you for the suggestion. I am really new to coding, would you mind showing what the code would look like in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is insufficient  as only the `$` is substituted with a `'\n'`.  To shorten the string, set a *null character*. [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74851422/how-to-copy-lines-up-to-a-certain-character-from-one-text-file-into-another-in-c/74851787#comment132096905_74851422)

```
if (cmt_ptr != NULL)
{
    *cmt_ptr = '\n';
    cmt_ptr[1] = '\0';  // Add
}
```

Alternative approach:  Use different ways to print when a `$` is found.  No `tmp_line` needed.

```
while (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, input) != NULL) {
  char *cmt = strchr(line, '$');
  if (cmt) {
    int length = cmt - line;
    printf("%.*s\n", length, line);  // Print limited character array.
  } else {
    fputs(line, output);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `fgets` is over-complicating the issue, since there's no need to read full lines.  Just read one character at a atime.  eg:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        FILE *input = argc > 1 ? xfopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;
        FILE *output = argc > 2 ? xfopen(argv[2], "w") : stdout;
        enum { print, noprint } state = print;
        int c;
        while( (c = getc(input)) != EOF ){
                switch( c ){
                case '$':
                        state = noprint;
                        break;
                case '\n':
                        state = print;
                }
                if( state == print ){
                        putc(c, output);
                }
        }

        return 0;
}


FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
        FILE *fp = path[0] != '-' || path[1] != '\0' ? fopen(path, mode) :
                *mode == 'r' ? stdin : stdout;
        if( fp == NULL ){
                perror(path);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return fp;
}
```

Comment: `*getc()` certainly handles the case on embedded _null characters_ in the stream.  `fgets()` likely has better performance.  I suppose we could use `fread()` and get the best of both.